# Not able to generate Extent Reports when classes running parallel with TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testing, extent

When classes running parallel with TestNG we are not getting Extent Report but TestNG report is getting updated. Please find the below sample code and versions which i am using.
If we are running only one class (TestClass1.java) then Extent Report will generate.

Selenium version 3.4.0

Extent Report Version : 3.0.6

**ExtentReportBase.java**

```
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test;


@BeforeTest
public void setUp()
{
    //where we need to generate the report
    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test-output/MyReport.html");
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

    // Set our document title, theme etc..
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("My Test Report");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Test Report");
    htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
    htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK); 

}

@AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result)
{
    if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
        test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + "Test Case failed due to below issues", ExtentColor.RED));
        test.fail(result.getThrowable());
    }

    else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + "Test Case Passed", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }

    else
    {
        test.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + "Test Case skipped", ExtentColor.YELLOW));
    }

}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown()
{
    extent.flush();
}
```

**TestClass1.java**

```
@Test
public void functionality1Test1()
{
    test = extent.createTest("functionality1Test1");
    Assert.assertTrue(1 > 0);
}

@Test
public void functionality1Test2()
{
    test = extent.createTest("functionality1Test2");
    Assert.assertEquals("Google", "goo");
}

@Test
public void functionality1Test3()
{
    test = extent.createTest("functionality1Test3");
    Assert.assertNotEquals("Google", "Google");
}
```

**TestClass2.java**

```
@Test
public void functionality2Test1()
{
    test = extent.createTest("functionality2Test1");
    Assert.assertTrue(1 > 0);
}

@Test
public void functionality2Test2()
{
    test = extent.createTest("functionality2Test2");
    Assert.assertEquals("Google", "goo");
}

@Test
public void functionality2Test3()
{
    test = extent.createTest("functionality2Test3");
    Assert.assertNotEquals("Google", "Google");
}
```

**testng.xml**

```
`<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="classes">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestExtentReport.TestClass1"/>
      <class name="TestExtentReport.TestClass2"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->`
```

Comment: Can you post your testng.xml file from which you are running your test.

Comment: Now I have added testng.xml file

Answer (score 1):

use extent report jar 3.x.x

and in your base class use extent variables like:

```
static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter; 
static ExtentReports reports;
ExtentTest logger;
```

Answer (score -1):

These 3 are instance variable for each class invocation they need to be initialised so declare them static will solve your problem.

```
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test;
```

**Declare them as -**

```
static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
static ExtentReports extent;
static ExtentTest test;
```

I tried with same code. It is working fine for me.

Please refer the attached screenshot.
[ExtentReportResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eREtd.png)[image: BaseClass]

**Let me know if that works.**

Comment: If it solved your problem then please accept the answer.

Comment: when running parallel we can not use Extent test as static.. because it may not give the correct report.. because at the time of flush if we have 2 or 3 test cases result it may append all one test case